# Editing the  loaded Polygons in Google Map

Tags: google-maps

I have Polygons(Points) saved in my SQL database and I need to edit the loaded Polygons in googlemap and save it back to the database.

I successful loaded the Polygons in the google map. For editing which event should I use to select a particular polygon and update the same in the database?

i'm trying to call the polygon click event but it was not successful.

Please provide me the best approach to edit the loaded Polygons in GoogleMap?

Comment: How are you calling the DB update? What is the error in the click event? Please show some code.